# hive regexp_extract weirdness

Tags: regex, hive

I am having some problems with regexp_extract:

I am querying on a tab-delimited file, the column I'm checking has strings that look like this:

```
abc.def.ghi
```

Now, if I do:

```
select distinct regexp_extract(name, '[^.]+', 0) from dummy;
```

MR job runs, it works, and I get "abc" from index 0.

But now, if I want to get "def" from index 1:

```
select distinct regexp_extract(name, '[^.]+', 1) from dummy;
```

Hive fails with:

```
2011-12-13 23:17:08,132 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2011-12-13 23:17:28,265 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201112071152_0071 with errors
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
```

Log file says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Thanks,
Mario

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the docs https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF it appears that regexp_extract() is a record/line extraction of the data you wish to extract.

It seems to work on a first found (then quit) as opposed to global. Therefore the index references the capture group.

0 = the entire match
1 = capture group 1
2 = capture group 2, etc ...

Paraphrased from the manual:

```
regexp_extract('foothebar', 'foo(.*?)(bar)', 2)
                                  ^    ^   
               groups             1    2

This returns 'bar'.
```

So, in your case, to get the text after the dot, something like this might work:
`regexp_extract(name, '\.([^.]+)', 1)`
or this
`regexp_extract(name, '[.]([^.]+)', 1)`

**edit**

I got re-interested in this, just a fyi, there could be a shortcut/workaround for you.

It looks like you want a particular segment separated with a dot `.` character, which is almost like split.
Its more than likely the regex engine used overwrites a group if it is quantified more than once.
You can take advantage of that with something like this:

Returns the first segment: `abc`.def.ghi
`regexp_extract(name, '^(?:([^.]+)\.?){1}', 1)`

Returns the second segment: abc.`def`.ghi
`regexp_extract(name, '^(?:([^.]+)\.?){2}', 1)`

Returns the third segment: abc.def.`ghi`
`regexp_extract(name, '^(?:([^.]+)\.?){3}', 1)`

The index doesn't change (because the index still referrs to capture group 1), only the regex repetition changes.

Some notes:

- This regex `^(?:([^.]+)\.?){n}` has problems though.
  It requires there be something between dots in the segment or the regex won't match `...`.
- It could be this `^(?:([^.]*)\.?){n}` but this will match even if there is less than n-1 dots,
  including the empty string. This is probably not desireable.

There is a way to do it where it doesn't require text between the dots, but still requires at least n-1 dots.
This uses a lookahead assertion and capture buffer 2 as a flag.

`^(?:(?!\2)([^.]*)(?:\.|$())){2}` , everything else is the same.

So, if it uses java style regex, then this should work.
`regexp_extract(name, '^(?:(?!\2)([^.]*)(?:\.|$())){2}', 1)` change {2} to whatever 'segment' is needed (this does segment 2).

and it still returns capture buffer 1 after the {N}'th iteration.

Here it is broken down

```
^                # Begining of string
 (?:             # Grouping
    (?!\2)            # Assertion: Capture buffer 2 is UNDEFINED
    ( [^.]*)          # Capture buffer 1, optional non-dot chars, many times
    (?:               # Grouping
        \.                # Dot character
      |                 # or,
        $ ()              # End of string, set capture buffer 2 DEFINED (prevents recursion when end of string)
    )                 # End grouping
 ){3}            # End grouping, repeat group exactly 3 (or N) times (overwrites capture buffer 1 each time)
```

If it doesn't do assertions, then this won't work!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to make 'groups' no?

```
select distinct regexp_extract(name, '([^.]+)', 1) from dummy;
```

(untested)

I think it behaves like the java library and this should work, let me know though.

Comment: ha, weird, the MR job runs with that, but it returns still the contents of index 0!

Comment: and I just tried for kicks with index 2, and then it fails with

2011-12-13 23:33:41,377 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2011-12-13 23:34:01,465 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201112071152_0074 with errors
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask

again.... weird weird weird....