# In Hive I need to Get numeric value after a particular word is it possible?

Tags: hive, hiveql

i want to get a numeric value immediately after a particular word in string
 In hive for example : 
APDSGDSCRAM051 in that i need to get numeric value after word RAM 
is it possible in hive

Note: its not a fixed length string

Comment: You can use regex to do this. I m not sure how to implement that in Hive, but here is sample for java which does the thing as you want. http://ideone.com/hdW7de.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, you need to use substr and instr pre-defined hive functions:

```
create table str_testing (c string);
insert into table str_testing values ('APDSGDSCRAM051');
select substr(c, instr(c, 'RAM') + 3) from str_testing;
OK
051
Time taken: 0.243 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: can we convert the resulted value to binary?

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8497735/3831557), you can implemented in hive as

```
select regexp_extract(name, '\\d+', 0) from <table_name>;
```

Note: I do not have environment for Hive configured so you can check this by running at your end. Ya this will work only for first set of numbers found in your string, if you string has numbers at multiple places this might fail.

Comment: can we convert resulted value to binary ?

Comment: that you can check ... there must be a way by using UDF if no inbuilt function available