# Regex Hive not working

Tags: regex, hive

I am trying to extract `44` from the String

```
Created RSA Key 45555 from Intelligent Expense ID 44|54?HOTEL?345555|||||
```

using Hive `regexp_extract`.

The regex I currently have is `(^\ID\s)\d*` and it is not working.

Can somebody help me please

Comment: use this `(\ID\s)\d*`..remove the anchor (`^`)..though it will be better to use `(\ID\s)\d+`

Comment: Thanks. but this brings in ID also. If I want only 44, what would the regex be

Comment: change the capturing group : - `ID\s(\d+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` marks beginning of string which is not always the case, because it does not necessarily start with `ID`. So you can use

```
(ID\s)\d*
```

For capturing only numbers after `ID` and you should use `\d+` instead of `\d*`

```
ID\s(\d+)
```

This capturing group can be accessed using `1` as mentioned **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497090/hive-regexp-extract-weirdness)**