# How to extract all string matches in Hive/what's the equivalent of REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL in Hive?

Tags: sql, regex, hive, amazon-redshift

What's the equivalent of REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL in Hive? I'm trying to get all matched occurrences of a regular expression in Hive or Redshift.

Comment: Not sure, but this might be pertinent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497090/hive-regexp-extract-weirdness/8497735#8497735

Comment: Supply a data sample including required results

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at `REGEXP_SUBSTR`. Doesn't have to the ability to return a specific capture group but you should be able to accomplish most of the same things using look ahead and look behind patterns. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html

Comment: This is SQL, not Hive.

Comment: There is no REGEXP_SUBSTR function available in hive.

Comment: OP asked for a Redshift solution ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: LOL did you delete your first comment. Actually I see 4 mentions if Hive before one casual mention of Redshift at the very end (not even in the title-but I’ll edit it now)

Comment: You should provide an example of how to return all regex matches. REGEX_EXTRACT will do the same thing in Hive but merely mentioning it won’t get him anywhere.